Arab Supremacy in hadith?
Malice for the Bani Haashim (migrants) and Ansaar is kufr (heresy) whilst malice for the Arabs is hypocrisy.’ [Tabarani in Al-Kabir, Vol. 11, Page 118, Hadith 11312]
The best of the people are the Arabs; the best of the Arabs are the Quraysh and the best of the Quraysh are the Banu Hashim.’ [Daylami in Al-Firdaws, Vol. 1, Page 178, Hadith 2892]
Are these Hadith authentic and if they are could they be about how Arabs are  superiority to other races

I am not commenting on the ruling of this but the hadith do not imply any sort of superiority of Arabs over others, neither in privelleges nor in authortiy. Rather, it simply signifies superior lineage and ancestry, which is a very real thing in Islam. It doesn't have any effect on you as a person and doesn't give anyone else any right above you, it has absolutely zero effect in any way whatsoever but superiority and inferiority in lineage are proven from hadith. The Bani Hashim is the clan of the Prophet PBUH and so the ones of his clan share ancestry with him. Thus, they are superior-

in lineage to others because of sharing ancestry with the best creation of Allah SWT. The ansaar were those who believed in the Prophet PBUH and his companions who migrated to Medinah when the people of their own homeland and tribe had disbelieved in them and plotted to kill them. Thus, they are of the greatest of people after the migrants (Because the migrants were the first of the believers in the Prophet PBUH).

As for Arabs as a whole, they are the same race as the race the Prophet PBUH, the best creation of Allah SWT was born in. And so, those born with Arab lineage are superior in terms of lineage to non-Arabs. Once again, this gives them no real right over non-Arabs nor any extra ability in Islam. An Arab can be a fasiq, a kafir, and go to hell, while a non-Arab can be one of the greatest saints to walk over the earth. Lineage does not matter in any other discussion except of itself.

Sorry, I could not find your sources. Could you please give a link or at least some hint where to look at? Thanks.

There is clear proof in the hadith that all races are equal and are able to only surpass eachother in piety.

انك لست بخير من احمر ولا اسود الا ان تفضله بتقوى


Definitely, you are not better than a white person or a black person except if you become superior in taqwa (piety)

This hadith is from Musnad Ahmad (RAA) 21407 and comes in different narrations as seen in the link below
[https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2016/01/04/racism-no-favor-skin-color/][1]
The one I have mentioned is from the kitaab Zaad-Ut-Taalibeen by Moulana Ashiq Ilahi (RAA), 103

Fairly decent answer. However, I suggest you do write some content w.r.t. the ahadith in question. Perhaps take some ideas from my comments and do some research accordingly for them. This answer can be edited to be much better.

I do not see Arab Supremacy in this hadith. Even the Quran says the opposite.

وَ مِمَّنْ حَوْلَكُمْ مِنَ الْأَعْرَابِ مُنَافِقُونَ وَ مِنْ أَهْلِ
الْمَدِينَةِ مَرَدُوا عَلَى النِّفَاقِ لَا تَعْلَمُهُمْ نَحْنُ
نَعْلَمُهُمْ سَنُعَذِّبُهُمْ مَرَّتَيْنِ ثُمَّ يُرَدُّونَ إِلَىٰ
عَذَابٍ عَظِيمٍ
And from whom (is) around/surrounding you from the Arabs (are)
hypocrites and from the city's/town's people they were accustomed to
rebelling/mutiny on the hypocrisy, you do not know them, We know them,
We will torture them twice, then they be returned to great
torture.(9:101)

Such hadith are about Ahl al-Bayt, who are mentioned in the Quran.

إِنَّمَا يُرِيدُ اللَّهُ لِيُذْهِبَ
عَنكُمُ الرِّجْسَ أَهْلَ الْبَيْتِ وَ يُطَهِّرَكُمْ تَطْهِيرًا
truly God wants to eliminate/wipe off from you the filth/torture,
people (of) the House/Home, and He purifies you purification
(33:33)

And "this house" is not the physical house. It is the house of revelation and divine knowledge.
And their supremacy is not because of their race, but for their extreme piety according to this verse:

يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّا خَلَقْنَاكُمْ مِنْ ذَكَرٍ وَ أُنثَىٰ وَ
جَعَلْنَاكُمْ شُعُوبًا وَ قَبَائِلَ لِتَعَارَفُوا إِنَّ أَكْرَمَكُمْ
عِندَ اللَّهِ أَتْقَاكُمْ إِنَّ اللَّهَ عَلِيمٌ خَبِيرٌ
You, you the people, that We created you from a male and a female, and
We made/created you (into) nations/communities and groups/tribes to
know each other, that truly (the) most honoured/kind of you at God
(is) your most fearing and obeying, that truly God (is) knowledgeable,
expert/experienced.(49:13)


Assalamu Alaykum,
Islamically there are many proofs to suggest that no one has superiority over anyone except in piety and Taqwa. In the Qur'an, Allah says:
إِنَّ أَكْرَمَكُمْ عِندَ اللَّهِ أَتْقَاكُمْ
Indeed, the most noble in the sight of Allah is the most righteous of you.
(Surah Hujurat 49:13)
The Prophet (SAW) said in his final sermon:
"An Arab does not have superiority over a non-Arab, nor does a non-Arab have superiority over an Arab"
This is enough evidence to suggest that Arabs, or any race in general, has superiority over another.
Insha'Allah this answered your question.


The best of people are the Arabs, the best of the Arabs are the Quraysh, the best of the Quraysh are the Banu Hashim, the best of the non-Arabs are the Persians, the best of the Sudanese are the Nubians, the best dye is safflower, the best hair dye is henna and indigo, and the best wealth is land.
Musnad ad-Daylami (2892) Imam ash-Shawkani said in Fawa'id al-Majmua'h (p. 414): 'It is fabricated; and in its Isnad: unknowns.'
Ibn Hajar mentions the chain of transmission from this Hadith in his Tahqiq of this Musnad (4/308-10) and states that he has no biography of the narrator A'bdul Rahim ar-Razi (unknown) and that in it are multiple weak narrators such as Abu al-Qasim al-Kufi or Al-Kisai al-Kufi.

Rather, we have an authentic Hadith, which is contrary to the above:

The Messenger of Allah ﷺ during the middle of the days of Tashriq said: "O people, indeed your Lord is One, and your father is one. There is no superiority of an Arab over a non-Arab, nor a non-Arab over an Arab, nor a white over a black, nor a black over a white, except by piety. [...]"
Musnad Ahmad (23489) graded Sahih by Shaykh Albani in As-Sahihah (6/449-52 - #2700)



Hatred of Banu Hashim and the Ansar is disbelief, and hatred of the Arabs is hypocrisy.
Mu'jam al-Kabir (11312) graded Da'if Jiddan by Shaykh Albani in Ad-Da'ifah (7-380-1 - #3372)

